# Magento Patch SUPEE-11219

Tags: supee-11219

I have applied a patch SUPEE-11219 on my Magento 1.9.3.2.
I am getting a known issue (Accounts with Password length < 7 will be locked)
Is there any way , How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the class `validate-password` from your login template, you should be fine.